# What are strong named keys for?

Tags: visual-studio, strongname

In .NET, what are strong named keys for? I read about it before but it just isn't sticking in my head.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131181/what-is-a-snk-for

Answer (score 1):

They're used for identifying an assembly. More specifically, who created the assembly.

One reason to sign an assembly with a strong name key is to add it to the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

According to (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(VS.71).aspx) it prevents the assembly from being changed by anyone.
It protects the (semi) compiled assembly for being changed.