# Calculating MD5 checksum of an asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, hash, md5, checksum

I have a published asp.net website for which I need to calculate the MD5 check sum (to ensure its integrity at a later time).

As the website folder has multiple files, is there a way that is usually used for calculating MD5 hash in such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

You want to sign your assemblies with a Strong Name. .Net offers SNK, see this link: [The Secrets of Strong Naming](http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/28/strongnaming.html)

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131181/what-is-a-snk-for) has a great explaination as well.