# Can we use .snk file for a c++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, snk

It would be great if someone could help me on this.I have recently started exploring strong named assembly.I wanted to understand the following:

- `.snk` file and what does it contains?
- can we use this `.snk` file for a c++ dll?
- Is this only limited to `.net` assemblies?
- can we use this `.snk` to load or unload dlls?
- How secure is this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131181/what-is-a-snk-for

Comment: I have already read answers regarding that question. It doesnot explain about the usage about .snk for a c++ dll @Cirrus

Comment: It is stated everywhere "for .NET assemblies". You can write manages assemblies with C++ but that's probably not what you want.  For unmanaged assemblies you will probably have to look at [SignTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/signtool)