# Creating a custom .SNK file

Tags: .net, assemblies, private-key, public-key, snk

How can we generate a custom [.SNK file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131181/what-is-a-snk-for) (used to sign an assembly with a strong name), if I already have my private/public key pair (in arbitrary format, but for the sake of the clarity, let's say we've generated it on linux, using [ssh-keygen](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/))?

Comment: I'm not sure that is a supported option, but I'm very curious to find out if I'm wrong!

Comment: SNK format is well explained here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9ef264e-1a74-4f48-b93f-3e2c7902f660/determine-contents-of-a-strong-name-key-file-snk?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 0):

You can store the keys in Microsoft CNG formerly CSP and the SNK can be easily pointing to the Key container .. that way you can even have the keys store in an HSM, this however create a problem with sharing keys on different machine .. if the keys are on a pkcs12 file you can easily make a batch file to store it in the KeyContainer and then use it

So you same key pairs on each machine which can be security if these keys are very important.

On other hand you can use also the CSP or CNG Provider

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
    <KeyContainerName>YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME_HERE</KeyContainerName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you also want the key to show up in the 'properties' section of the project then you can add the following section

```
<None Include="$(KEY_CONTAINER_HERE)">
  <Link>Properties\App.snk</Link>
</None>
```

If you can generate pk12 or pfx file .. with the key pairs, then you can use sn.exe -i   .. to generate p12 file you can use openssl

Comment: This doesn't explain how to get the keys (from an arbitrary format) into the key container.

Comment: if you can generate pk12 or pfx file .. with the key pairs, then you can use sn.exe -i  <pfx file name>  <container name> .. to generate p12 file you can use openssl ..